# Changing propeprty setter behaviour from a base class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, properties, base-class

I'm working with Telerik RadScheduleView and have implemented the IAppointment class into a child 'Job' class that I have defined. The 'Start' and 'End' (DateTimes) properties are found in the IAppointment class (of which I inherit). Navigating to the 'Public Virtual' method (in the IAppointment class) shows me a { get; set; } but I can't change it to say, for example, display a MessageBox on setting a new value to Start or End. It says MetaData in the tab, is this just something I am not able to edit? Is there a way I can override this access method somehow??

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to override a non virtual base member?

Comment: I'm asking is it possible to define the 'set' part of the access method of a base class' property of this type.

Comment: `set` and `get` are both just methods with syntactic sugar poured on top.  In this case they get compiled down to methods called `set_Start` and `get_Start`, etc.  If they are properly `virtual`, you can override them.  There shouldn't be a **class** called `IAppointment` though, unless they messed up when naming it.  Anything that has an `I` prefix should be an `interface`.  I think the class you'd have to look at is the class that *derives* from the interface, to see if the properties are `virtual` at that level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name `IAppointment` would indicate to me that it is not a class you are inheriting, but an interface you're implementing - however, I'm not familiar with Telerik products and their naming conventions might just be weird, so, taking what you say at face value, yes you ought to be able to override a property defined as virtual.

If, for example, we have the following class defined somewhere, but accessible, so that we may inherit, and which exposes a `virtual` member:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int J { get; set; }
}
```

Then we can inherit and `override` - we may still access the base implementation, but also "inject" our own, if required:

```
public class B : A
{
    public override int J
    {
        get
        {
            return base.J;
        }
        set
        {
            base.J = value;
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't for the life of me imagine why you'd want to show a message box from within the logic of property accessors, and can't stress enough that you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!! Appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

As Mr Disappointment mentioned I'd expect IAppointment to be an interface.

If it is indeed a class you could use the [new modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier) and do something along the lines of this.

```
public class Job : IAppointment
{    
    new public DateTime End
    {
        get
        {
            //get the value directly from the base class
            return base.End;
        }
        set
        {
            //display your messagebox here

            //then pass the value to the base class
            base.End = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a property in your derived class which will eventually get and set the propety of base class no need to override.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is confusing. IAppointment isn't a class, its an interface.

Is this your situation?

1. There is an interface called IAppointment with 2 properties namely Start and End. ( http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/t_telerik_windows_controls_scheduleview_iappointment.html )
2. There is a base implementation named AppointmentBase (or the more derived, Appointment). (http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/t_telerik_windows_controls_scheduleview_appointmentbase.html)
3. You are building your own class which is inheriting from the AppointmentBase.
4. You want the setter of AppointmentBase.End to show a messageBox but you dont know how to add this logic.

In that case i have good news.

AppointmentBase only servers virtual members so you can easily override the Set property

```
class Job : AppointmentBase
{
    public override DateTime End
    {
        get { return base.End; }
        set
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unbelievable!");
            base.End = value;
        }
    }
}
```